# RISC-V ISA most important 40 instructions to be implemented

Tags: riscv

I have to implement RISC-V architecture (ISA for pipelined processor) in C++. As all ISA can not be implemented, can some one tell me about most important approx. 40 Instructions set which i should include?
please help

Answer (score 3):

The most important subset is RV32I. It is about 40 instruction in size.

https://riscv.org/specifications/
Chapter 2

> RV32I was designed to be suficient to form a compiler target and to
>   support modern operating system  environments.   The  ISA  was  also 
>   designed  to  reduce  the  hardware  required  in  a  minimal 
>   implementation.  RV32I  contains  47  unique  instructions,  though  a
>   simple  implementation might cover the eight SCALL/SBREAK/CSRR*
>   instructions with a single SYSTEM hardware instruction  that  always 
>   traps  and  might  be  able  to  implement  the  FENCE  and  FENCE.I 
>   in- structions as NOPs, reducing hardware instruction count to 38
>   total.  RV32I can emulate almost any other ISA extension (except the A
>   extension, which requires additional hardware support for atomicity).